# Authenticated Proxy Checker for nodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I have tried using the proxy-checker package from NPM to check on proxies if they work and this code has been working fine so far:

```
var proxyChecker = require('proxy-checker');

proxyChecker.checkProxy("proxy.foo.com", 8080, {
  // the complete URL to check the proxy
  url: 'http://www.example.com',
  // an optional regex to check for the presence of some text on the page
  regex: /Example Domain/
},
  function (host, port, ok, statusCode, err) {
    console.log(host + ':' + port + ' => '
      + ok + ' (status: ' + statusCode + ', err: ' + err + ')');
  }
)
```

but now I got to deal with authentication proxies which goes something like this

```
proxy:{
    host:"proxy.foo.com",
    port:8080,
    user:"proxyuser",
    password:"123"
}
```

What are the possible ways to implement authenticated proxies for a proxy checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide the ip address in the format username:password@ip_address

```
var proxyChecker = require('proxy-checker');

proxyChecker.checkProxy("proxyuser:123@proxy.foo.com", 8080, {
      url: 'http://www.google.com',
},
function (host, port, ok, statusCode, err) {
   console.log(ok)
})
```